# Sort and assign the order to query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to sort a collection, then add a virtual property to the result which is their numerical order in which the results where displayed as.

So for example, we have a collection called calls, and we'd like to ascertain the current call queue priority as a number so it can be synced to our CRM via reverse ETL.

We have to do this inside of the query itself because we don't have an intermediary step where we can introduce any logic to determine this logic.

So my current query is

```
db.getCollection('callqueues').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
    'invalidated': false,
    'assigned_agent': null
}
},
{ $sort: {
    score: -1, _id: -1
} },
{
 $addFields: {
   order: "<NEW ORDER PROPERTY HERE>",
 }
   },
])
```

So I was wondering how would I insert as a virtual property their order, where the first element after the sort should be 1, second 2, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (since mongoDB version 5.0) is to use `$setWindowFields` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {invalidated: false, assigned_agent: null}},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {score: -1, _id: -1},
      output: {
        order: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CjjT10FGEOp)

**EDIT**: If your mongoDB version is earlier than 5.0, you can use a less efficient query, involving `$group` and `$unwind`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {invalidated: false, assigned_agent: null}},
  {$sort: {score: -1, _id: -1}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, data: {$push: "$$ROOT"}}},
  {$unwind: {path: "$data", includeArrayIndex: "order"}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$data", {order: {$add: ["$order", 1]}}]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example < 5.0](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fj44jnylOVR)

Comment: Unfortunately we're not up to date with the latest mongo versions  I can see about bumping it in the future but as of right now we are bound to 4.4.18

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Perfect! This is largely for an experimental service so we can assess the performance hit, but this does exactly what I need! Thank you so much!